# COUNTIF with multiple criteria to return different results

Tags: excel, excel-2010, countif

I am trying to query a set range for the presence of three specific text values and have the formula set a specific text value based upon the result.  The cells will not contain any other value.  The values are `Go`, `Needs Work - Pending`, and `No Go`.  This spreadsheet tracks sub-task completion, such that if any cell in the range contains `No Go` the result is `No Go`; if any cell contains `Needs Work - Pending` the result is `Needs Work - Pending`; if all cells contain `Go` the result is `Go`.  The formula for one value and one result works fine:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B12:B21,"Needs Work - Pending"), "Needs Work - Pending", "Go")
```

I have been unable to determine how to add the next level.  Functionally I would like the following to work:

{
IF range contains `No Go` return `No Go` BREAK
IF range contains `Needs Work - Pending` return `Needs Work - Pending` BREAK
ALL ELSE return `Go` RETURN
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to put a formula in one cell that looks at the range B12:B21 and:

1. If any cell in that range has "No Go" you want it to return "No Go".
2. If none of them are "No Go" then check to see if any are "Needs Work - Pending". If any of them are "Needs Work - Pending" then return "Needs Work - Pending".
3. If none of the cells in that range are "No Go" and none of them are "Needs Work - Pending" you want it to return "Go".

If I've understood this correctly, then I believe you should be able to use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B12:B21,"No Go")>0,"No Go",IF(COUNTIF(B12:B21,"Needs Work - Pending")>0,"Needs Work - Pending","Go"))
```

EDIT:  Changed from "Needs Work" to "Needs Work - Pending" to match up with user pnuts' edit to the original question.

Comment: Works perfect, you are platinum! I tried the formula with and without the ">0" at the end of the trailing COUNTIF parenthesis and it seems to work identically. Can you explain the merit of adding it? Does it speed up the formula by ignoring blank cells?

Comment: I just did that to be extra explicit so you could see what was happening.